# Returning non utf8 from php

Tags: php, json

I am having a problem while reading values from a database and passing them as json.

I read fine the value from DB and it is well read but when I try to pass it to a json format, it gives null.

This is my code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, lat, lon FROM POI_Table WHERE attribution=:attribution");
    $stmt->execute(array(':attribution'=>$attribution));

$x = -1;

while($res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $x++;
    $data[$x] =  array(
    "id" => $res['id'],
    "title" =>  $res['title'] , 
    "lat" => $res['lat'] , 
    "lon" => $res['lon']
      );
}
if($x > -1){
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

When I have a word with accents ex: "música" it returns null.

I don't know why because it is working reading values from other DB. So I think it is related to accents format. How could I convert or encode to right format before adding to array?

Comment: With `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv`.

Comment: Perfect. I did with mb_convert_encoding. Thanks